# How to concatenate a list data type and an int32 data type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I found some code online that looks very, very interesting.  I am trying to get it to run; getting an error on this line.

```
# create a DataFrame aligning labels & companies
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': labels, 'companies': companies})
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

When I look in the Variable Explorer window, I see that companies is a list of size 28 and labels is a type int32 and size (259,).  I don't see how this is going to work, but apparently the author got it to work somehow.

https://www.mlq.ai/stock-market-clustering-with-k-means/

```
#dfMod = dfMod.fillna(0)
#dfMod = dfMod.replace(to_replace ="NR", value ="0") 


#format the data as a numpy array to feed into the K-Means algorithm
####################################################################
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# define instruments to download
companies_dict = {
 'Amazon': 'AMZN',
 'Apple': 'AAPL',
 'Walgreen': 'WBA',
 'Northrop Grumman': 'NOC',
 'Boeing': 'BA',
 'Lockheed Martin':'LMT',
 'McDonalds': 'MCD',
 'Intel': 'INTC',
 'Navistar': 'NAV',
 'IBM': 'IBM',
 'Texas Instruments': 'TXN',
 'MasterCard': 'MA',
 'Microsoft': 'MSFT',
 'General Electric': 'GE',
 'Sprint': 'S',
 'American Express': 'AXP',
 'Pepsi': 'PEP',
 'Coca Cola': 'KO',
 'Johnson & Johnson': 'JNJ',
 'Toyota': 'TM',
 'Honda': 'HMC',
 'Mitsubishi': 'MSBHY',
 'Sony': 'SNE',
 'Exxon': 'XOM',
 'Chevron': 'CVX',
 'Valero Energy': 'VLO',
 'Ford': 'F',
 'Bank of America': 'BAC'
}

companies = sorted(companies_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

# Define which online source to use
data_source = 'yahoo'

# define start and end dates
start_date = '2019-01-01'
end_date = '2020-01-10'

# Use pandas_datareader.data.DataReader to load the desired data list(companies_dict.values()) used for python 3 compatibility
panel_data = web.DataReader(list(companies_dict.values()), data_source, start_date, end_date)

print(panel_data.axes)


# Calculate daily stock movement
# Find Stock Open and Close Values
stock_close = panel_data['Close']
stock_open = panel_data['Open']

print(stock_close.iloc[0])

row, col = stock_close.shape

# create movements dataset filled with 0's
movements = np.zeros([row, col])

for i in range(0, row):
    movements[i:row] = np.subtract(stock_close[i:row], stock_open[i:row])


for i in range(0, len(companies)):
    print('Company: {}, Change: {}'.format(companies[i][0], sum(movements[i][:])))


plt.figure(figsize=(18,16))
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(movements[0][:])
plt.title(companies[0])

plt.subplot(222, sharey=ax1)
plt.plot(movements[1][:])
plt.title(companies[1])
plt.show()

# import Normalizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
# create the Normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()

new = normalizer.fit_transform(movements)

print(new.max())
print(new.min())
print(new.mean())

# import machine learning libraries
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# define normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()

# create a K-means model with 10 clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, max_iter=1000)

# make a pipeline chaining normalizer and kmeans
pipeline = make_pipeline(normalizer,kmeans)

# fit pipeline to daily stock movements
pipeline.fit(movements)

# predict cluster labels
labels = pipeline.predict(movements)

# create a DataFrame aligning labels & companies
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': labels, 'companies': companies})

# display df sorted by cluster labels
print(df.sort_values('labels'))

# PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 

# visualize the results
reduced_data = PCA(n_components = 2).fit_transform(new)

# run kmeans on reduced data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
kmeans.fit(reduced_data)
labels = kmeans.predict(reduced_data)



# create DataFrame aligning labels & companies
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': labels, 'companies': companies})

# Display df sorted by cluster labels
print(df.sort_values('labels'))

# Define step size of mesh
h = 0.01

# plot the decision boundary
x_min, x_max = reduced_data[:, 0].min() - 1, reduced_data[:,0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = reduced_data[:, 1].min() - 1, reduced_data[:,1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Obtain abels for each point in the mesh using our trained model
Z = kmeans.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

# define colorplot
cmap = plt.cm.Paired

# plot figure
plt.clf()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest',
 extent = (xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()),
 cmap = cmap,
 aspect = 'auto', origin='lower')
plt.plot(reduced_data[:, 0], reduced_data[:, 1], 'k.', markersize=5)


# plot the centroid of each cluster as a white X
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],
 marker='x', s=169, linewidth=3,
 color='w', zorder=10)

plt.title('K-Means Clustering on Stock Market Movements (PCA-Reduced Data)')
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I figured it out.  This link helped.  https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/stock-market-clustering-with-k-means-clustering-in-python-4bf6bd5bd685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily convert both of them into dataframe then concate them, it's less complex and all will be valid!

Comment: That's an excellent point.  I guess the simplest solution would be the best, right.